# How do I make a pay command with npm module discord-money?

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am making a currency system for Project Star, a discord server, I made my own bot and started coding it. I wanted a pay command so I tried making one. Here is my code.

```
    
    if(user === message.author) {
      return message.channel.send("You cannot pay yourself!")
    }
    
    money.updateBal(message.author.id, -wanted).then((i) => {
      message.channel.send(`Processing...`);
    })
    
      if(wanted > moneyBal) {
        message.channel.send("Error: Insufficient Funds")
      } else if(wanted < moneyBal) {
        money.updateBal(user.id, wanted).then((i) => {
          message.channel.send(`Transaction Completed with $${wanted} Sent.`);
        })
      }
```

When I type the command c!pay, it responds **Processing...** and doesn't send a message after that. If I send more than what I have, it does the same thing but my balance changes to -. For example. c!pay @TheRealGamer1YT 6, my balance is -1. It sends the money though. Even if I don't have the amount. How do I fix this to if what you want to pay is more than what you have, it displays an error?

Comment: This might not directly solve your problem, but it looks like you are are executing `updateBal` before checking balances unless the validation is inside of `money`. It seems like you should add an `else` at end of your conditionals and move that block. I'm noticing that there is also no fencing, transactions, ect so the user sending money can send 2 requests very quickly and be able to send money that they may not actually have.

Comment: So, can you say the code of how I should do it? I don't know how to fix it.